# Wordpress - Blank Lines before every <?php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to configure Google Search Console and enable it to read my sites xml.

However, there appear to be 6 blank lines and therefore I get the error below:

This page contains the following errors:
error on line 7 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Upon inspection of my wordpress theme files, pretty much all of them seem to have 6 blank lines before the php opening `<?php`

[image]

I have no idea what is causing this. I am not an expert at php so please be aware. Just trying to configure my site for google really.

All help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with simply deleting those first 6 lines?

Comment: I'm not clear on what Google search console has to do with XML or your WordPress PHP files

Comment: the problem is, it seems to be on every single file. When I delete them, they just come back :S?